# Regular expression for the multiple email address

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression like below:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\.|-|_]*[@]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\.|-|_]*[.]{1}[a-z]{2,5}$
```

From above regular expression:
(1) a@gmail.com ==> valid 
(2) b@gmail.        ==> invalid
(3) c@gmail         ==>invalid

The above regular expression is only for single email address.
But now, I want like below:
(1) a@gmail.com                          ==> valid
(2) a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com  ==> valid
(3) c@gmail,d@gmail.com          ==> invalid

The email address should be in full format no matter how many email user fill in. 
How should I modify it? Can someone help me?

Comment: [`^[A-Za-z0-9._-]*@[A-Za-z0-9._-]*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,5}(,\s*[A-Za-z0-9._-]*@[A-Za-z0-9._-]*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,5})*$`](https://regex101.com/r/dC7bN3/1)

Comment: your validation potentially marks some valid email addresses as invalid. (for example, a `+` character should be allowed before the `@`. [related reading](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Comment: You should [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Regex](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Comment: Note that you should use `\-` to select a hyphen, not a `|-|`

Comment: Also, `@gmail.com` is working using your Regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9\.|-|_]*[@]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\.|-|_]*[.]{1}[a-z]{2,5})(,[A-Za-z0-9\.|-|_]*[@]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\.|-|_]*[.]{1}[a-z]{2,5})*?$
```

The first part will select one email address:

```
([A-Za-z0-9\.|-|_]*[@]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\.|-|_]*[.]{1}[a-z]{2,5})
```

Then the second part is similar, however it must start with a comma (`,`), and the whole section is optional (`?`)

```
(,[A-Za-z0-9\.|-|_]*[@]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\.|-|_]*[.]{1}[a-z]{2,5})*?
```

Check out [this demo on RegExr](http://regexr.com/3d1cc)

---

**Thanks to [@Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) for pointing out my previous RegEx allowed a trailing `,`**

Comment: This will also allow a trailing `,` as in `a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com,`

Comment: I do not know if you noticed, but `|-|` in the pattern will never match a hyphen, and I believe OP wants to match a hyphen. Also, the `?` quantifier at the end only allows 2 emails in the input while the question states *no matter how many email user fill in*.

Comment: I added a `*` after the second part, just before the `?`, to allow an unlimited number of email addresses. Since the OP already had the expression, I changed it to do what he wanted, though I will inform him of the hyphen thing too.

Comment: @Druzion I think you have a mistake in your regex beacause `@gmail.com` is working for me also `a@gmail.com,@gmail.com`

Comment: @AkramLazkanee Yes it does, though the OP original RegEx also does. I'll inform him of that.